# OpenCV: How to apply a filter on vectors obtained through calcOpticalFlowFarneback?

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I've found and constructed an optical flow map, I'd now like to remove any vectors that fall below a certain threshold. This is how I've set up my Farneback optical flow:

```
if (prevgray.empty() == false ) {
calcOpticalFlowFarneback(prevgray,gray,flowUmat, 0.4,1,50,2,5,1.2,0);
flowUmat.copyTo(flow);

for( int y=0; y<original.rows; y+=7){
    for (int x=0;x<original.cols;x+=7){

        const Point2f& flowatxy=flow.at<Point2f>(y,x);
        line(original, Point(x,y), Point(cvRound(x+flowatxy.x*4), cvRound(y+flowatxy.y*4)), Scalar(0,255,0));
        theta=atan((flowatxy.y)/(flowatxy.x)); //very unsure of this
        circle(original, Point(x,y), 0.1, Scalar(0,0,0),-1);
    }
}
gray.copyTo(prevgray);

    }
else{gray.copyTo(prevgray);}
```

I was thinking of something of comparing each vector to neighbouring vectors or to an average of all the vectors in the image.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any vectors that fall below a certain threshold you first need to estimate the length, if you want e.g. discard long motion vectors. Your loop will than look like:

```
...    
const Point2f& flowatxy=flow.at<Point2f>(y,x);
float flowVectorLength = flowatxy.x * flowatxy.x + flowatxy.y * flowatxy.y;
if( flowVectorLength > threshold * threshold)
    continue;
...
```

Actually the motion vector length has to be computed by `float flowVectorLength = sqrt(flowatxy.x * flowatxy.x + flowatxy.y * flowatxy.y);` but to avoid the computational complex estimation of the square root (sqrt) you can compare it with the square of the `threshold`.